# Excel Input Box VBA Error Checking Problem

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code that I changed. I cannot figure out VBA for the life of me. If this was c++ it would have taken me 30 seconds to write. I am still getting the errors.

```
Sub CodeFinder()

    Dim userInput As String
    Dim errorCheck As String

    userInput = InputBox("Please enter the code to search", "Code Search Engine")

    errorCheck = Cells.Find(What:=userInput, _
                       After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                       MatchCase:=False)

    If errorCheck = False Then
        MsgBox ("Error")
    Else
        Cells.Find(What:=userInput, _
                   After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                   False).Activate
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: You should format your code as code so it's easier for us to read. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) how.

Answer (score 3):

If `Cells.Find` fails it returns `Nothing`. So you need to assign it to a variable, and check its value before trying to `.Activate` it.

In fact you should also check the return value of `InputBox` in case Cancel was clicked.

EDIT: Still contains a number of errors.

1. `Cells.Find` returns a `Range`, but you are trying to assign it to a `String` variable. (Also don't forget that `Range` and `String` variables have different assignment statements.)
2. You then try to compare the variable to `False` instead of checking that it isn't `Nothing`.
3. You then need to activate the found `Range` rather than trying to find it again.

Comment: Hey I edited the post to the code I have written but I am still getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CodeFinder()

    Dim userInput As String
    Dim rFound As Range

    userInput = InputBox("Please enter the code to search", "Code Search Engine")

    If Len(userInput) > 0 Then
        Set rFound = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=userInput, _
                           After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                           MatchCase:=False)

        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            rFound.Select
        Else
            MsgBox "No cells found"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```